# Disable stop on entry by default?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for my Python projects, but most of the time I don't need the debugger to stop the script on run. By default, when I hit F5, the script is stopped at the first line and I have to press F5 again to start it.

This can be changed by editing the project-related `launch.json`; though I'd like it to be that way by default (and also for non-project files, like test scripts for example).

Is there any way to do that? There's not parameter related to that feature that I can set in my `settings.json`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer more or less randomly. So basically, you can't configure it globally, but you can create (or modify) a Python debugging environment. Once you do that, you can configure it and set `stopOnEntry` to `false` on that environment. After that, if you choose the right debugger, `stopOnEntry` will never be enabled (for that environment).

Answer (score 0):

There is/was? an option

"stopOnEntry": false;

that you could add to your launch.json file.  It isn't clear to me whether that option still exists or is buggy. See, for example

[stopOnEntry issues](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/984).  In any case, I would try to add the option and see what happens.

Comment: Well this option exists but only project-wise (VS Code doesn't know that setting if I edit the JSON file for parameters)